# Filter by multiple topics in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I’ve had a look through the form and have been unsuccessful in finding a solution for this. I currently have a page that displays a bunch of posts, with a simple @post = Post.all

I’m trying to create form that can filter by one of the columns, topics that Post have.

So basically on the left side it will have all the posts,
The right side will have all the unique topics of posts. The user can select one or more of the topics, then click submit, and the posts With the selected topics will be shown.

I’m able to show the unique topic, but unsure how to organise it so it filters after submitting. My current thought process is to create a form with all the topics. When the user presses a few topics, then submits, it filters by the selected topics. But I’m unsure on how to do the filtering in the controller as the amount of topics selected is dynamic. For example if it was just one post. It’s a simple @post = Post.where(:topic params[:chosen]) but I’m unsure how to filter it dynamically on different amounts of topics. Like if 2 or more topics are chosen.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement the index method of controller something similar to this (Note: The code is not tested)

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :construct_filters, only:[:index]

  def index
    @posts  =  Post.where(@query) # => Posts.where({"topic" => ["topic1","topic2"]}) or Post.where({}) in the case of no params passed(return all posts)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js # In case of remote true submit, respond with index.js.erb and update the listing
    end
  end

  private

  # Generic method to construct query for listing
  def construct_filters
    @query = {}
    # Pass the chosen from the form as comma separated string inside filter hash.
    # Example params received: filters: {"topic" => "topic1,topic2"}
    if params["filters"].present? 
      params["filters"].each do |k,v|
        # You can modify the below line to suit your needs if you are not passing as comma seperated
        filter_value = filter_value.split(',') 
        @query[k] = filter_value if filter_value.present?
      end
    end
    # @query  = {"topic" => ["topic1","topic2"]}
  end
end
```

Having a generic filter method and a constructing parameter as filter hash will allow you to add more filters in future.

You can implement checkbox or multi select dropdown for selecting topics in your views, may be with input name as `filters[topic]`. Hope this helps!